# Getting TeXShop to complete last compile before starting new one?

Tags: compiling, texshop

Consider the error described here: [Unclean .aux file causes "file ended while scanning use of \@newl@bel" error. Why is it not purged?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131709/unclean-aux-file-causes-file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-newlbel-error-wh)

The basic solution to this is that one should always finish a compile completely before recompiling. To finish a compile requires a fair few clicks of the mouse/keyboard - something which is very frustrating.

Thus I'm looking for a way to streamline this process. Namely what I want is the following:

- Say I press Command+T to compile (this is at least what it is on my mac) and it then reaches an error. I want the compiler to stop and show me the error.
- Now if I press Command+T  again (in the text-editor part of TexShop) I want it to 1) Complete the compile it just did, and 2) Start a new compile.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: All too often once you get an error that stops compilation trying to complete the compilation only leads to many more errors caused by that initial error. That's not always true but all too often it is. if you want the compile to continue try pressing the Return which conti ues the process.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I thought one could continue ignoring further errors though? This is what I would want to do here.

Comment: It is possible to start up a compile to ignore errors but what is the point? All too often one error elads to an infinite more errors and the aux file is still messed up. The only safe thing to do is correct the error and clean out the aux files to staart from a clean slate.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I note that the top-voted answer in the question I link to above states that you should `always let TeX finish'.

Comment: It says "let TeX finish" but it also mentions (although not very clearly) that there are two ways of doing this: either continue to compile by ignoring any further errors until the end of the file is reached, or finish immediately by pressing X. For the reasons Herbert outlined above, the second option is preferable (and faster). When you finish with X then the `.aux` file is almost always properly written and should not cause an error on recompile (as opposed to 'killing' a compile and/or restarting a new compile without exiting the previous one).

Comment: @Marijn Ok, thank you for your comment. This makes sense. Though my question still holds, of weather I can get TeXshop to `finish immediately' the last compile automatically before it starts a new compile (without me having to go into the console and pressing X)